# How accurate and fast is androids network location provider?

Tags: android, geolocation

I'm making a weather application that needs to know current location that uses to report status of weather near/around a persons phone.

It doesn't have to be more accurate than 100m maybe and quick (few seconds) in bad weather, so user doesn't get bored waiting for result.

So, how accurate and fast is androids network location provider?

Thanks!

Comment: First, you need to determine what the accuracy is of your weather forecast provider. If you think you have a weather forecast provider that provides accuracy down to 100m, I would be interested to know who it is.

Comment: The service I have to use is limited to around 1-1.5km per pixel of image data, so according to the answer below network location provider will be good enough for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I use the android network location provider. I typically get a 1500m range of accuracy however the fix is really fast. Good for a general location.

You can retrieve the accuracy in meters by using Location's getAccuracy() if you want to test on your own.

If that is not good enough accuracy, then register for both the network location provider and GPS location provider. While it is trying to get the GPS location you will at least start out with a generic location and just update on higher accuracy readings.